# Как передать данные геолокации в параметр функции JS? fetchDataGeo(currentLat,currentLon) эти аргументы undefined

Tags: javascript

```
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log('Geolocation is supported!');
        function geoSuccess(position) {
            currentLat = Math.round(position.coords.latitude * 100) / 100;
            currentLon = Math.round(position.coords.longitude * 100) / 100;
            console.log(currentLat);
            console.log(currentLon);

        }
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
    }
    else console.log('Geolocation is not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.');


    fetchDataGeo(currentLat,currentLon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вызывать функцию там, где широта и долгота известны:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log('Geolocation is supported!');
    function geoSuccess(position) {
        var currentLat = Math.round(position.coords.latitude * 100) / 100;
        var currentLon = Math.round(position.coords.longitude * 100) / 100;
        console.log(currentLat);
        console.log(currentLon);

        fetchDataGeo(currentLat,currentLon);
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
}
else console.log('Geolocation is not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.');
```

P.S. Вы округляете географические координаты примерно до километра.

Answer (score 0):

```
 componentWillMount = () => {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log('Geolocation is supported!');
        function geoSuccess(position) {
            let currentLat = Math.round(position.coords.latitude * 100) / 100;
            let currentLon = Math.round(position.coords.longitude * 100) / 100;
            console.log(currentLat);
            console.log(currentLon);
        }
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
    }
    else console.log('Geolocation is not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.');

    fetchDataGeo(currentLat,currentLon).then(data => {
        this.setState({
            weatherItems: data
        });
    });
    fetchDataForecastGeo(currentLat,currentLon).then(data => {
        this.setState({
            weatherItemsForecast: data
        });
    });
}
```

// Yes but then can't setState in React!!! I need to pull out this coordinates